# Django Form error "Enter a list of values" for ManyToMany field

Tags: django

While validating a ManyToMany field, i'm getting the "Enter a list of value" error.
Here is my code

models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ManyToManyField("PollCategory")
```

forms.py

```
class PollForm(forms.ModelForm):
        created_by = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=50)
        class Meta:
            model = Poll
            widgets = {
                'category': Select(),
            }
```

template

```
<form action="{% url add_poll %}"  method="post">{% csrf_token %}
         title : {{ form.title }} <br>
         category : {{ form.category }}</div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

i'm getting this error when **form.is_valid()** is executed. It may be because from template i'm passing the "string" which will be a value of select option but in the ManyToMany filed it is required to save the 'id' which should be an integer.

I have searched the net for solution of above problem but could not find which fits my situation.

How can i successfully validate and save the 'category' field in Poll model ?

Comment: can you post your full traceback

Answer (score 2):

> It may be because from template i'm passing the "string" which will be a value of select option but in the ManyToMany filed it is required to save the 'id' which should be an integer.

You're close. It's expecting a list, not a single string. Below is the method `to_python` for the `MultipleChoiceField`.

```
def to_python(self, value):
    if not value:
        return []
    elif not isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_list'])
    return [smart_unicode(val) for val in value]
```

Knowing now that you need a list, you can try to subclass the `MultipleChoiceField` and provide your own `to_python`:

```
class SingleMultipleChoiceField(MultipleChoiceField):
    widget = Select

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            return []
        return [value]

    def validate(self, value):
        if self.required and not value:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'])
        if not self.valid_value(value):
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'] % {'value': value})
```

I haven't tested this, but give it a shot. Or, ideally, just use the standard widget instead of the `Select` widget, and this whole issue goes away. I'm not sure why you're trying to force only a single element into a `ManyToManyField`; they are built for multiple objects.

Comment: @naveenyadav did you also set `category = SingleMultipleChoiceField(..)` ?